# Calling asynchronous I/O method from sync code

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task, wait

I have this piece of code (in synchronous method):

```cs
// ...
var processingTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(x => Task.Run(async () =>    
      await CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync(accounts[x], cancellationToken)))
    .ToList();

var processingTasksAggregate = Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);

Task.WaitAny(globalStatusMonitoringTask, processingTasksAggregate);
```

I am especially interested in this part:

```cs
Task.Run(async () => await CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync(accounts[x], cancellationToken))
```

Would it make a difference (from a possible deadlock perspective) if I removed the `Task.Run`? I.e. changed it to:

```cs
CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync(accounts[x], cancellationToken)
```

I wanted to remove it, because queueing the task on a thread pool (via `Task.Run`) seemed redundant, but my colleague advised me no to, because of possible deadlocks

The whole method is run as background job in sth similar to Hangfire:

[image: hangfire-like-jobs-processor]

[Edit 1]: **It's a .NET Framework** (not Core) application.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without knowing what is inside of `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync()`. But yes, it *could* make a difference.

Comment: "switching to different thread pool (via Task.Run)" what do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant `queueing the task on a thread pool` - I updated the question. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @JohnWu can't we black-box the `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync`? I.e. there're various method called from there, it's hard to specifically say all stuff that's happening.
It's an async method calling await on few external services (API / Db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it make a difference (from a possible deadlock perspective) if I removed the Task.Run?

Possibly. There are two parts to the [common deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (link to my blog):

1. Blocking on asynchronous code. Your code is doing this with `Task.WaitAny`.
2. A context that only allows one thread at a time.

Since your code clearly has (1), then you can conclude it will deadlock if it has (2). Common contexts that can cause deadlocks include ASP.NET pre-Core and GUI thread contexts. If your app doesn't have a one-thread-at-a-time context, then there is no chance of deadlock.

> I wanted to remove it, because queueing the task on a thread pool (via Task.Run) seemed redundant

Not really. "Asynchronous" does not mean "run on a different thread", so the two aren't redundant. The question is whether removing the `Task.Run` would work. It might, or it might not. If this code is run in a single-threaded context, then removing the `Task.Run` would cause a deadlock. If `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync` may run synchronously (i.e., due to cache hits), then removing the `Task.Run` would cause the invocations to be run serially rather than in parallel, and that may not be desirable, either.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `asp.net core` application (not just old school `asp.net`) there is no problem with task deadlock. `SynchronizationContext` (which can cause deadlock without `ConfigureAwait(false)`) is null in `asp.net core`. [There isn’t a SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET Core.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)

Also without `Task.Run` - `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync` will be executed on your current thread until the first `await` inside. With `Task.Run` - entire `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync` will be executed out of your main execution. You can fix it with adding `Task.Yield` in the beginning of `CallApiAndUpdateSthAsync`.

Comment: It's a .NET Framework application - I updated the question

Comment: @MrPatience is it asp.net core or not? Because you can create ASP.NET Core on full framework.

Comment: As in question, it's a background processing middleware based on simple .NET Framework. 4.7.2 It's not using ASP.NET nor ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @MrPatience According to what you described I don't see any reason for deadlock in your code. Probably you should ask your colleague what he meant.